# How would I create a button that links to records on my database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am currently building a site which is based around an interactive button.

The Process of the site:

1. Someone signs up using their name, address and a unique username
   (e.g. joebloggs, richardbloggs).
2. Once signed up they will be able to click the interactive button.

What I want the button to is:

- Once the button is clicked it will automatically update a piece of text
  under it with the person that has clicked its username e.g.
  'joebloggs has clicked'.
- If another person then clicks the button it will then say e.g.
  'richardbloggs has clicked'.

**The Key feature is the once it is CLICKED it updates STRAIGHT AWAY**

Comment: `<button onclick="talk_to_server_via_ajax();">Click me</button>`

Comment: This is not the type of question Stack Overflow is meant for. You need to start on this and come to us with specific problems in your attempt. We don't write code for you...

Comment: Considering the number of downvotes and close votes there are on this question, it seems like most people disagree with you.  You need to prove you've made *some* effort towards solving this problem on your own, not just come here with a laundry list of requirements like this is some freelance site, with an emphasis on the *free*, where we right code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should do it the following way:

1. Attach an event to the button just as @Marc B suggested
2. In the function for the event do a [`jQuery.ajax` request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), sending the users name (`type` to `POST` would be a good idea and the users name inside `data`)
3. On the server create a PHP file (for example `setname.php`) that has the URL you used for the ajax request
4. In the PHP file take the name from `$_POST['name']` and [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) it into any file (let's say `lastbuttonclicker.txt`)
5. Go back to the JS and make a `window.setInterval(..., 1000);` which runs another JS function
6. In that function from step 5, do another ajax request (via `jQuery.ajax` and add it via [`jQuery.fn.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), **not [`jQuery.fn.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and don't use [`jQuery.fn.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)!!!** That way users could write HTML into other users interfaces doing *very bad things*) to another PHP file (for example `getname.php`)
7. In that PHP file just do `<?php echo file_get_contents('lastbuttonclicker.txt'); ?>`

But after all be aware, that users can put offensive names there. But that is a topic for itself.

EDIT: You should also ensure, that the content has a suitable length, at the **server side** (checking inside JavaScript has no impact to *bad people writing gigabytes of text to everybodys client and your server*).

EDIT 2: *<facepalm>* Of course you dont need step 7, just load the `lastbuttonclicker.txt` itself in step 6 instead of `getname.php`